# Long delay before receiving data in UDP socket after connecting network cable

Tags: .net, windows, sockets, udp

Short description of the setup: host A is connected directly to host B; both have fixed IPv4 addresses in the same subnet.

Host A (Windows 10) sends a 400 byte UDP packet (containing a payload of incrementing integers) every 10 ms to the fixed IP address of host B at port 5001
Host B (Windows 7) runs a simple .NET test program that opens a UDP socket, binds to 0.0.0.0 at port 5001 and waits for incoming UDP packets.

When starting the test program on host B the socket is created as follows:

```
byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
Socket udpSock;

private void Start()
{
   try
   {
      udpSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
      udpSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5001));
      udpSock.BeginReceive(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceiveUdp), udpSock);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

      if(udpSock != null)
      {
         try
         {
            udpSock.Close();
            udpSock = null;
         }
         catch { }
      }
   }
}
```

The receive callback looks like this

```
private void OnReceiveUdp(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   Socket sock = ar.AsyncState as Socket;
   if (sock == null)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Socket is null");
      return;
   }

   try
   {
      int nBytes = sock.EndReceive(ar);
      if (nBytes == 0)
      {
         MessageBox.Show("0 bytes received");
         return;
      }

      sock.BeginReceive(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceiveUdp), sock);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Normally everything works fine: no packets are dropped and we see no significant delays.

What we have noticed is that if we remove the cable from the NIC in host B, keep it detached for a few seconds and then reinsert it (host A keeps sending all the while) the UDP packets start appearing again in Wireshark relatively quickly but sometimes it takes 10 seconds or more until the UDP socket on host B starts receiving data again. The first data it receives is also not the first UDP packet captured by Wireshark but it appears many packets are dropped before they are suddenly passed on again to the transport layer. After that everything works fine again.

Has anyone else observed this phenomenon or knows what might be causing this relatively large delay?

Some additional notes:

- The delay is not fixed; sometimes there's even no delay at all. Other times it takes 10 seconds or more
- The problem also still occurs with all protocol/filter drivers disabled (except IPv4) for the network adapter
- We first observed this behavior in a kernel-mode driver we develop where we use Windows Kernel Sockets

I know UDP implies possible packet loss but I just find it strange that the packets do arrive in the network card but don't find their way up the network stack...

Comment: If the "connection" is dropped, what does the program on host B do? What happens in that program if it doesn't receive packets for some time, or if there's an error of some kind?

Comment: The program doesn't implement any timeouts; it opens the socket and keeps it open (so nothing happens when it doesn't receive packets for some time). Exceptions are caught and displayed in a message box but none are actually thrown during the test.

Comment: Anyway, without a [mcve] it's going to be very hard to help you. Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I also recommend that you use a debugger to step through the "B" receiving code in a debugger to see what it really does. Or at the very least add some very verbose and chatty logging.

Comment: I added the test program's code (the one running on host B)